# What does this complex contour integral represent?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, contour-integration, riemann-zeta, complex-integration

How would one evaluate the following complex contour integral in "Integral and Series Representations of Riemann’s Zeta
function, Dirichelet’s Eta Function and a Medley of Related
Results."

> The contour integral is stated as:
> $$\zeta(s)=\dfrac{\Gamma(1-s)}{2\pi i}\oint\dfrac{t^{s-1}}{e^{-t}-1}dt.$$
>
> (`Page-3` of this [PDF](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1208.3429v1.pdf))

where the contour of integration encloses the negative $t$-axis, looping from $t = −∞ − i0$ to
$t = −∞ + i0$ enclosing the point $t=0$.
The equivalence of $(2.11)$ and $(2.1)$ is well-described in texts (e.g. [35]) and is obtained by
reducing three components of the contour in $(2.11)$. A different analysis is possible however (e.g.
[12], Section 1.6) - open and translate the contour in $(2.11)$ such that it lies vertically to the right
of the origin in the complex $t$-plane2 with $σ < 0$ and evaluate the residues of each of the poles of
the integrand lying at $t = ± 2nπi$ to find:

> $$\zeta(s)=\dfrac i{2\pi}\Gamma(1-s)(2\pi i)^s\big(\exp(i\pi s/2)-\exp(-i\pi s/2)\big)\sum_{k=1}^\infty k^{s-1}.$$

Can you please explain the equivalence of the first expression and the Riemann Zeta function, as [35] does not explicitly state the correlation. In the first expression, what does t represent (is it a complex or real variable?). On page 22 of the The Riemann Hypothesis Origin, it states: to define the multi-valued function (-λ)^(z-1)=e^((z-1)*ln(-λ)), we choose the branch of ln(−λ) that is real for λ < 0. (In our case −λ=t and z=s)
In addition, how would one evaluate this complex (assuming t is complex, however knowing s can be complex) contour integral? Would one apply the method of branch cuts or the Residue Theorem, and if so; can you demonstrate it, as I am relatively new to the concept. Most importantly, can you also identify the contour being integrated over.

> Is this the contour being integrated over?
>
> [image][image]

> Or is this the contour?
>
> [image]

For further details

1. http://www.gauge-institute.org/riemann/RiemannZetaFunction.pdf
   (Pages `21-23` & Pages `28-30`)
2. http://www.maths.tcd.ie/pub/HistMath/People/Riemann/Zeta/EZeta.pdf
   (Page `34`)
3. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiemannZetaFunction.html
   (p`3` Page `25`)

Comment: Edward's book on the Riemann Zeta Function goes over these calculations in detail.  In particular, he shows how Riemann derived the first expression you are asking about.

Comment: Thank you, however if you look at a section on pg. 10 (http://books.google.bs/books?id=ruVmGFPwNhQC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false), it states that The definition of (-x)^s is (-x)^s= e^(s*ln(-x)), where the definition of ln(-x) conforms to the usual definition of lnz for z not on the real axis as the branch which is real for positive z; thus (-x)^s is not defined on the positive real axis...(Can you please explain this paragraph to me and kindly provide an image of the path described. Also, why must delta be taken to 0 or introduced in the first place? )

Comment: Thank you, however if you look at a section on pg. 10 (books.google.bs/…), it states that The definition of (-x)^s is (-x)^s= e^(s*ln(-x)), where the definition of ln(-x) conforms to the usual definition of lnz for z not on the real axis as the branch which is real for positive z; thus (-x)^s is not defined on the positive real axis...(Can you please explain this paragraph to me and kindly provide an image of the path described. Also, why must delta be taken to 0 or introduced in the first place? ) @Mustafa Said

Comment: @MustafaSaid (Notification)